# Java Parking Ticket Simulator - Class aggregation/copy constructors

Tags: java

Instructions:

• The ParkingTicket Class: This class should simulate a parking ticket. The class’s
responsibilities are as follows:
– To report the make, model, color, and license number of the illegally parked car
– To report the amount of the fine, which is $25 for the first hour or part of an
hour that the car is illegally parked, plus $10 for every additional hour or part of
an hour that the car is illegally parked
– To report the name and badge number of the police officer issuing the ticket

• The PoliceOfficer Class: This class should simulate a police officer inspecting parked
cars. The class’s responsibilities are as follows:
– To know the police officer’s name and badge number
– To examine a ParkedCar object and a ParkingMeter object, and determine whether
the car’s time has expired
– To issue a parking ticket (generate a ParkingTicket object) if the car’s time
has expired

My problem: I don't understand how I'm suppose to call both classes at the same time. In main, it's impossible. My current code actually works but I'm not sure if it's correct.  I don't understand how I'm suppose to only 'report' the objects in the ParkingTicket Class without 'knowing' them. Finally I don't understand how I'm suppose to generate a ParkingTicket object in the PoliceOfficer class without creating a field for the ParkingTicket class and adding that to the constructor. Thank you to whoever helps!

```
//Main:

public class chapter08_PE_08 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParkedCar car = new ParkedCar("HONDA", "CIVIC", "SILVER", "JPO4342", 132);
        ParkingMeter meter = new ParkingMeter(60);
        PoliceOfficer officer = new PoliceOfficer("Millard", "0723", car, meter);
        officer.issueTicket(officer);
    }
}


//Police officer class:

public class PoliceOfficer {
    private String officerName;
    private String officerBadge;
    private ParkedCar car;
    private ParkingMeter meter;

    public PoliceOfficer(String officerName, String officerBadge, ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter) {
        this.officerName = officerName;
        this.officerBadge = officerBadge;
        this.car = new ParkedCar(car);
        this.meter = new ParkingMeter(meter);
    }

    public PoliceOfficer(PoliceOfficer officer) {
        officerName = officer.officerName;
        officerBadge = officer.officerBadge;
        car = officer.car;
        meter = officer.meter;
    }

    public void setOfficerName(String officerName) {
        this.officerName = officerName;
    }

    public void setOfficerBadge(String officerBadge) {
        this.officerBadge = officerBadge;
    }

    public String getOfficerName() {
        return officerName;
    }

    public String getOfficerBadge() {
        return officerBadge;
    }

    public ParkedCar getCar() {
        return new ParkedCar(car);
    }

    public boolean examineCars() {
        return car.getMinutesParked() > meter.getTimePurchased();
    }

    public double calculateFine() {
        double totalTime = car.getMinutesParked() / 60;
        boolean fine = examineCars();
        double baseFine = 25.0;
        if (fine && totalTime > 1 && totalTime < 2) {
            return baseFine;
        } else if (fine && totalTime > 2) {
            double hourlyFine = 10.0;
            return baseFine + (hourlyFine * totalTime);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void issueTicket(PoliceOfficer officer) {
        ParkingTicket ticket = new ParkingTicket(officer);
        boolean fine = examineCars();
        if (fine) {
            System.out.println(ticket.generateTicket());;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Moving on...");
        }
    }
}

//Parking ticket class:

public class ParkingTicket {
    private PoliceOfficer officer;

    public ParkingTicket(PoliceOfficer officer) {
        this.officer = new PoliceOfficer(officer);
    }

    public String generateTicket() {
        return "\nParking Ticket" +
                "\n--------------" +
                "\nCar information: " + officer.getCar() +
                "\nOfficer name: " + officer.getOfficerName() +
                "\nOfficer badge number: " + officer.getOfficerBadge() +
                "\nYour fine: " + String.format("$%,.2f", officer.calculateFine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `public void issueTicket(PoliceOfficer officer) {` to take a `ParkedCar` as an argument rather than a `PoliceOfficer`.

You already have a `PoliceOfficer`, so no need to pass one. The `officer` variable on which you are calling the `issueTicket` already refers to a `PoliceOfficer` object. What you need is tell that officer what car deserves to be ticketed.

So this:

```
public void issueTicket( PoliceOfficer officer ) {
```

…becomes:

```
public void issueTicket( ParkedCar parkedCar ) { …
```

…and this:

```
officer.issueTicket( officer );
```

…becomes:

```
officer.issueTicket( car );
```